# Background Image scroll vertical in Blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, background

how do I retain a background image after we scroll vertically?

now, i am getting the image fit to the device height and width, but when i scroll down it will show white background.

here is my code

```
 BitmapField _bitmap ;
 private int phoneWidth = Display.getWidth();
 private int cellHeight = Display.getHeight();

 public MyScreen(){

    super(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

    final Bitmap background = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("black.jpg");
    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(USE_ALL_HEIGHT | USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Bitmap scaled = new Bitmap(phoneWidth, cellHeight);         
            background.scaleInto(scaled, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FIT);
            g.drawBitmap(0, 0, phoneWidth, cellHeight,
                         scaled, 0, 0);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };
    add(vfm);
 }
```

i am testing in simulator Blackberry 9900.

Comment: either use big images or use background color.

Comment: Is your background image supposed to **repeat** as you scroll, or should it fill the screen, but never *move* at all?